# Kivy, KivyPie and PiTFT

Tags: gui

I am developing application which must be very user-friendly. For fast prototyping, I made application via wxPython but it's appearance was not that good. So I decided to change my tool and Kivy seemed to be good choice. And there difficulties begin.

Firstly, I did all instruction on their site for Raspberry. After some time, I run some sample application but window didn't appear after all. By the way, I use PiTFT from Adafruit. Then I found KivyPie which promised to be clean image. However It didn't started on my board.

Did anyone make KIvy work on Raspberry Pi + PiTFT?
How did you achieve this?

With regards

Comment: First may I suggest you get it to work on a regular monitor or TV first. Then tackle getting it to work with the TFT. By your own admission Kivy "seemed to be good choice. and there the difficulties begin." so maybe you should reevaluate your choice of tool. Fianlly, you have asked essentially the same question 3 times. Each time it was closed as too broad or unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Generally you should ask questions on this site that are very specific and include all of the relevant material (e.g. is it throwing an error - if so what is the text of the error), what have you tried, what research have you done trying to debug/fix the issue yourself.

Comment: @SteveRobillard sorry for this. I admit my questions very broad. I just want to know, if anyone succeeded.

Comment: Boy, there are people who just loooove to close really useful questions... guess what folks, a solution to this would be very useful... sometimes in my experience having created two IPO-bound companies really good questions are, in fact, "broad"

Comment: The answer, incidentally, is spelled out in my answer to this thread which the 'too broad police' didn't close yet: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/37484/kivy-and-3-5pitft/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the kiby site contains instructions for [installing it on the Pi](http://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-rpi.html). The answer is yes, and following their instructions should work. if not I would suggest getting it to work without the PiTFT first to rule that out as a cause of the problem. I would also suggest that you are more likely to get an answer on their site as they are likely to have had more experience with tthis specific combination of hardware and software.